# A fast way to calculate the median difference between pairs of elements

Tags: algorithm, list-manipulation

I have a list of coordinate pairs, take for example the following list of three pairs:

```
exampleList = {
  {{151.335, 245.102}, {151.332, 245.187}}, 
  {{41.435, 245.021}, {41.3617, 244.986}},
  {{131.048, 243.364}, {131.046, 243.321}}
}
```

Assuming the list is very large, what is a fast one-liner to calculate the median difference between elements in each pair?

The output should be the same as:

```
Median[exampleList[[All, 1]] - exampleList[[All, 2]]]
```

Is this the fastest way to proceed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming the goal is to take the difference between each pair, and then take the median of all the differences:

```
Median[Flatten@Map[Differences, exampleList, {2}]]

112.296
```

To match the revised version of the OPs question:

```
-Median[Differences /@ exampleList]

{{0.003, 0.035}}
```

(or maybe `Flatten` this to get rid of the extra parentheses). The minus sign is there because `Differences` does the "second-first", whereas the OP wishes to have "first-second".

Comment: Oh, I meant that the pairs should be the coordinate, so a difference would be: {151.335, 245.102} - {151.332, 245.187} for the first element pair and so forth.  The answer should be a 2D coordinate.  Sorry, I was being unclear in my question.

Comment: I modified my question with a command that should give the right output.  I suspect this is a slower-than-optimal way to do things for large lists?

Comment: I think the modified version matches your description. I can't see why one would be much faster than the other, but you could do a test with `Timing` and a large input.

Answer (score 8):

Here's still another way.

```
-Median /@ Transpose@Flatten[Differences /@ exampleList, 1]
```

> {0.003, 0.035}

---

**Speed Comparison Using the Same Data Set (10^7 pairs of points)**

First, some data...

```
r := {RandomInteger[{130, 160}] + RandomReal[{0, 2}], RandomInteger[{230, 245}] 
     + RandomReal[{0, 2}]}
data = Table[{r, r}, {10^7}];
```

---

When I ran tests with 10^6 point pairs, no method consistently came out on top.
This changed dramatically, however, when 10^7 point pairs were used.

The OP's method: Timing (in sec), followed by output.

```
Median[data[[All, 1]] - data[[All, 2]]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {89.881627, {0.00444683, 0.000841006}}

---

The method of @ubpdqn:

```
({x, y} = Transpose[data]; Median[x - y]) // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {84.078609, {0.00444683, 0.000841006}}

---

David Carraher's Method:

```
Median /@ Transpose@Flatten[-Differences /@ data, 1] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {31.198662, {0.00444683, 0.000841006}}

---

The method of @bill s:

```
-Median[Differences /@ data] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {28.992141, {{0.00444683, 0.000841006}}}

Answer (score 6):

TO address the criticism of David Carraher

```
{x, y} = Transpose[exampleList]
Median[x-y]
```

yields:

{0.003, 0.035}

as desired

Comment: Does not give the desired results.

Comment: @DavidCarraher thank you for pointing out  my error which I hope I have corrected.

Comment: Meadian should be Median

Comment: It is now correct.

Comment: @DavidCarraher thank you for corrections: conceptual and typographic

Answer (score 5):

I've run @David Carraher's speed comparison on MMA V9 on my machine, and strangely, I get very different results. In a nutshell: Using packed arrays, the OP's method is faster than all others, by far.

```
r := {RandomInteger[{130, 160}] + RandomReal[{0, 2}], 
  RandomInteger[{230, 245}] + RandomReal[{0, 2}]}
data = Table[{r, r}, {10^7}];
```

The method of @bill s:

```
-Median[Differences /@ data] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {8.066461, {{-0.00213092, 0.000470161}}}

The OP's method:

```
Median[data[[All, 1]] - data[[All, 2]]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {8.398480, {-0.00213092, 0.000470161}}

The method of @ubpdqn:

```
({x, y} = Transpose[data]; Median[x - y]) // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {12.829734, {-0.00213092, 0.000470161}}

David Carraher's Method:

```
Median /@ Transpose@Flatten[-Differences /@ data, 1] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {8.233471, {-0.00213092, 0.000470161}}

### The same again using packed data

```
Needs["Developer`"]
data = ToPackedArray@data;
```

The method of @bill s:

```
-Median[Differences /@ data] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {7.373422, {{-0.00213092, 0.000470161}}}

The OP's method:

```
Median[data[[All, 1]] - data[[All, 2]]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {4.800275, {-0.00213092, 0.000470161}}

The method of @ubpdqn:

```
({x, y} = Transpose[data]; Median[x - y]) // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {10.422596, {-0.00213092, 0.000470161}}

```
-Median[Differences /@ data] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {7.960455, {-0.00213092, 0.000470161}}

Comment: I knew my computer was slow but the differences between our results are staggering. Nice idea to use packed arrays.

Answer (score 2):

This is slightly faster on packed arrays than the method adapted from @Nasser in the OP:

```
data = With[{n = 10^7}, 
  Transpose[{RandomInteger[{130, 160}, {2, 1 n}], 
     RandomInteger[{230, 245}, {2, n}]} + 
    RandomReal[{0, 2}, {2, 2, n}], {3, 2, 1}]]

-Median /@ Differences @ Transpose @ data // AbsoluteTiming
(* {5.429034, {{0.00338283, -0.000382357}}} *)
```

Compared with the OP:

```
Median[data[[All, 1]] - data[[All, 2]]] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {5.726198, {0.00338283, -0.000382357}} *)
```

If you compare it with @bill-s,

```
-Median[Differences /@ data] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {15.315464, {{0.00338283, -0.000382357}} *)
```

the upshot is that vectorized usually beats `Map`.

If you compare it with @ubpdqn, whose underlying idea is similar,

```
On["Packing"];
({x, y} = Transpose[data]; Median[x - y]) // AbsoluteTiming
(* messsages re unpacking *)
(* {29.155011, {0.00338283, -0.000382357}} *)
```

you see that unpacking can slow things down a lot.